# F# XML multiline documentation, Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xml, visual-studio, f#

I would like to add a multi-line XML documentation that will appear in the Intelli-Sense bubble when my mouse hover over it. See for example:

[image]

When I am using Visual Studio 2015, the following code works (see screenshots below), but now when I use Visual Studio 2017, it does not work anymore:

See the following screenshot taken in VS2015 and VS2017

VS2015:

[image]

VS2017:

[image]

After searching stackoverflow and other website, I tried some codes, but it is still not working.

```
// My failed guesses    

/// This also does not work
/// &amp; &#10; This does not work
let EXAMPLE3 = 2.0


/// This also does not work
/// \n This does not work
let EXAMPLE4 = 2.0

/// This also does not work
/// <br> This does not work
let EXAMPLE5 = 2.0

/// <summary>
/// This also does not work 
/// <para> &#13; This does not work </para>
/// </summary>
let EXAMPLE6 = 2.0
```

[How to add a line break in C# .NET documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279108/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-c-sharp-net-documentation?rq=1)

[Documenting F# Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121814/documenting-f-code)

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

How do I add a multi-line XML documentation in VS2017, for F#? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you put this on [Visual F# Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues). There was a lot of work done on the intellisense doc pop-up in the F# Tools so maybe it comes from there.

Comment: @s952163 Just added the issue to Visual F# Issues. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, leaving a completely blank line seems to work in VS 2017 but not in VS 2015:

```
/// First paragraph
///
/// Second paragraph
let example = 1
```

I don't know if this an intentional new addition.

Ignoring the `<para>` tag looks like a bug in VS2017.