# Visual Studio 2017: <list> not showing correctly on hover (xml documentation)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, xml-comments

If you hover over something (class, method,...) that's got xml documentation (`///<summary></summary>`) in VS17 (15.6.2), you get this little popup that shows the comments properly formatted.

I tried to make a list (copied from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/list)):

```
/// <summary>Here is an example of a bulleted list:
/// <list type="bullet">
/// <item>
/// <description>Item 1.</description>
/// </item>
/// <item>
/// <description>Item 2.</description>
/// </item>
/// </list>
/// </summary>
```

But the popup only displays it in a single line:

```
Here is an example of a bulleted list: Item 1. Item 2.
```

I also tried to add `<term>` to it (like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#list)) but all I get is:

[image]

I've tried with the other `type`s too (and also without) but no change. Is this a bug? How do I fix it?

Comment: If you want to show descprition as multiline text you can set paragraph break - <para/>  [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279108/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-c-sharp-net-documentation)

Comment: @Wojtman I already tried `<para></para>`, which seems to be broken a bit too: Instead of just adding a single line break (like you'd expect, see the 2nd screenshot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44565660/2016165)) it adds 2, which makes it looks even worse.

Comment: I agree. I wish the formatting of summaries on-hover was a little more robust. We often define new (one-line) classes that inherit from another class with generic types (using StrangeIOC signalling system - if you were curious).

It usually looks something like:
```public class SomeCustomSignal : Signal<string, int> { }```

I would like to be able to list out what the signal parameters are, similarly to any function, but I can't get it to look nice.

Comment: still broken; no list/table views in the tooltip in VS17 after a few years!

Comment: This was finally fixed in Visual Studio 2019!

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround:

```
/// <summary>Here is an example of a bulleted list:
/// <list type="bullet">
/// <item>
/// <description><para>&#x02022; Item 1.</para></description>
/// </item>
/// <item>
/// <description><para>&#x02022; Item 2.</para></description>
/// </item>
/// </list>
/// </summary>
```

Comment: Interesting, that's a nice workaround and looks exactly the same as the comments that were finally fixed in VS 2019.