# How to Add Comments to C# 9 Records

Tags: c#, comments, record, c#-9.0

C# 9 records have a short form like so:

```
public record Car(int CarId, int Cylinders, string Make, string Model);
```

How can I add documentation comments to the properties of the record? Note that this is different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613788/what-is-the-right-way-to-add-comments-with-c9-record) other question which asks about the long form.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct way appears to be as simple as this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Represents a car.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="CarId">The id of the car.</param>
/// <param name="Cylinders">The number of cylinders.</param>
/// <param name="Make">The make of the car.</param>
/// <param name="Model">The model of the car.</param>
public record Car(int CarId, int Cylinders, string Make, string Model);
```

This does work in the IDE's IntelliSense (tests on VSCode) when you create a new instance of this record (ie `new Car(...)` will give you the information of the different parameters).

There appears however to be a problem in the compiler's warning system itself if you have `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` enabled in your `.csproj`. For every parameter you will get the following warning pair:

```
warning CS1572: XML comment has a param tag for 'CarId', but there is no parameter by that name
warning CS1573: Parameter 'CarId' has no matching param tag in the XML comment for 'Car.Car(int, int, string, string)' (but other parameters do)
```

So it does indeed work, but the compiler both moans about the parameter being not documented and having a documentation for a parameter that does not exist.

[Put record parameters in scope of xml docs #49134](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/49134) might fix the issue in the next version, hopefully.

Comment: FYI for others, the error was resolved in .NET 5.0.200 SDK, released March 02, 2021

Comment: Intellisense (starting to type 'param') and auto-filling in of all params upon adding 3 slashes above the record (as you can above a class) still doesn't work with updated VS2019 as of 9/2021